# Get a new unix timestamp when writing to a file

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, sensors

First post so apologies for any formatting issues ect.

Context - Using a PIR sensor to log visits to a store using a Pi-3.
My aim here is to write a new unix timestamp to a file every time the sensor detects motion.

Below is what code i have so far, this outputs a text file with a unix timestamp. but the stamp appears to be the same for every detection

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO_PIR = 11
print "PIR Module Test (CTRL-C to exit)"
GPIO.setup(GPIO_PIR,GPIO.IN)     
Current_State  = 0
Previous_State = 0
Variable= int(time.time())

try:

 print "Waiting for PIR to settle ..."

 while GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)==1:
   Current_State  = 0    
 print "  Ready"    

while True :   
 Current_State = GPIO.input(GPIO_PIR)

  if Current_State==1 and Previous_State==0:      
    print "Motion detected"    
    Previous_State=1
    file = open("textFile.txt", 'a+')
    file.write(Variable + "\n")
   file.close()
  elif Current_State==0 and Previous_State==1:
    print "  Ready"
    Previous_State=0


  time.sleep(0.01)      

except KeyboardInterrupt:
print "  Quit"
```

Comment: Please, put text information as text in the question, not as images (or screenshots). It is easier to read, to copy/paste...

Comment: Textfile image has been removed.

Comment: Look at your code.  Does it write the same value to the file every time, or does it not?  Just read through the code and imagine you are the computer executing it.  What does it do?

Comment: Hey, Sorry I'm quite new at programming.  but my stab at it would be that i have it set to writing the same information each time a motion is detected? Would it make sense to change the Variable to something like the datetime.datetime.now() function?

Comment: ```Variable``` is called once globally and that value is used whenever you write it. Put ```Variable= int(time.time())``` inside the ```if``` in ```while loop```. Thus the current time is updated every time you detect a motion.